# Edit or delete HTML code added to Concrete5 webpages

Tags: html, concrete5-8.x

I am using Concrete5 version 8.5.9 on PHP version 7.4.

I have added a HTML code on my homepage through HTML block added to the global area.

Now I wish to make some modifications to the HTML code but I am unable to find out the way through which I can do it.

One way is to revert the page version through Dashboard>Sitemap>Name of page

But here, the biggest problem comes:

If you have made modifications to this page after the HTML code was added then your recent modifications also reverted back to that time and you need to correct them.

It’s a bad thing!!

So I am searching for a way through which I can only delete or modify that HTML code only.

If there’s any way, then please let me know.

Thanks

I have tried to go through Dashboard>sitemap>webpage>revision
But unfortunately I am not able to get, what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a global area, you can visit the stacks and you will find the global areas there, you can find the stacks from the dashboard to change it.

If not, you will need to do some hard code to get the blocks from the global area class.

I hope this helps.
Good luck !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).